# Is it possible to record variable changes?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Unreal Engine 4 and there is a bug where the mouse is not constrained to the window.

I am trying to debug the mouse position, but it am not sure how I would do it.

Every time I set a break point at the mouse position visual studio will pause the application, it is just really hard to debug because there are so many pauses.

I am wonder if it is possible to record variable changes? For example set a special break point at a variable and visual studio will only very briefly pause the application, look at the variable and put the value into a list.

I could just log the mouse position, but I want to get away from using log all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by using the "When Breakpoint is Hit" window.  Set the breakpoint, right-click it and choose "When hit..."

[image]

On this window, check both the "Print a message" and the "Continue execution" checkboxes.  Then update the string you want to print to include the value(s) that you want printed (variable values and expressions needs to be wrapped in {} to be interpreted as such.  Setting "Continue execution" makes the debugger not break at the line, instead, it will just log and continue.  The messages are printed to the Debug >> Output window at runtime.

[image]